# Is there any example of connecting from spark structured to kafka using sasl oauthbearer mechanism

Tags: spring-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, sasl

I have to connect to spring kafka from spark structued streaming program using a sasl_ssl/oauthbearer mechanism. I will receive the token from inhouse adsf portal. I have been trying to find an example or detailed mechanism of how this integration works. I understand that in Java we use a callback handler that is used to get the token and validate it. How exactly does it work when Spark structured streaming is used(Java Spark/Scala Spark).

I have gone through apache spark documentation but that does not provide any information on the sasl/oauthbearer mechanism.